# Windows Phone - Display control in front of other controls

Tags: c#, windows-phone, listpicker

I am coding a Windows phone application.  In one of my pages, I have a list picker which is populated from the database, therefore its size depends on how many records there are in the database.

My main issue is that if there are records more than a certain amount, the "extra records" are displayed behind the next control in the page and cannot be accessed.

How can I give the list picker precedence over other controls such that it is displayed in front?  To give you an idea of what I want, imagine having multiple pictures in Microsoft Word and setting one picture as 'Bring to Front'.

As you can see, the entry "tommy_shaw" is greyed out.  This is because it is overlapping the Transaction ID textbox.  Attempting to click on "tommy_shaw" would only load up the keyboard to enter text in the Transaction ID textbox.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can fix it with grouping; which ever one you have in the code first will be displayed first. If you have two images grouped together, then it is going to try and display both of them at the sametime.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer?

Comment: The image gets uploaded but it is not being displayed.  I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this site and didn't know there was two ways

Comment: Are you uploading it from a url or from a file?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it using Canvas.zIndex = 1 in the xaml file